# Asp.net core 2.0 site running on LightSail Ubuntu can't access AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-lightsail

I have a website that I've build with Asp.net core 2.0. The website gets a list of files sitting in my ASW S3 bucket and displays them as links for authenticated users. When I run the website locally I have no issues and am able to access S3 to generate pre-signed urls. When I deploy the web app to LightSail ubuntu I get this incredibly useful error message : AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied.

At first I thought is was a region issues. I changed my S3 buckets to use the same region as my Lightsail ubuntu instance (East #2). Then I thought it my be a CORS issues and made sure that my buckets allowed CORS.

I'm kinda stuck at the moment.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ?

Comment: Nope. Sorry.  Gave up this effort and switched to Serverless api.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, then i solved it by creating an environment variable. To add environment variable permanently in Ubuntu open the environment file by the following command

```sh
sudo vi /etc/environment
```

then add your credential like this

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=YOUR_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YOUR_SECRECT_ACCESS_KEY
```

Then save the environment file, and Restart your asp core app.